# How to get a selected treeview node full name?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a treeview which list the directory on a hard drive starting with  "Reonance Tunneling" with the path as

```
string MyPath = @"D:/Documents/Reonance Tunneling";
```

I also have a selected treeview node as:

```
TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
```

I want to disable the delete folder button but if the full path is MyPath. The following code works.

```
if ("D:/Documents/" + newSelected.Text == MyPath)
{
     BntDeleteFolder.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
     BntDeleteFolder.Enabled = true;
}
```

I would like to get the name correspond directory to newSelected plus its parent's directory using a method instead of hard-wiring it.

Comment: It is a common trick to store the full path in each Node's Tag and to display only the last level of the Path. Then you can compare ((string)newSelected.Tag)==MyPath

Comment: Thanks! That work with the modification of newSelected.Tag.ToString() instead of (string)newSelected.Tag.